# How do I fix Siri's pronunciation of a name for all family members at once?

Tags: iphone, ios, siri

Summary: How do I correct Siri's pronunciation of my name and have that pronunciation apply to all members of my family?

I have an unusual last name.  (Call it "Weirdlastname", pronounced "Smith".)  Unsurprisingly, many members of my family share the name and I have many of them listed as contacts in my phone.  We all pronounce it the same way.

Siri mispronounces the name.  I know how to correct the pronunciation on a contact-by-contact basis (see [How do I get Siri to pronounce my name correctly?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29210/how-do-i-get-siri-to-pronounce-my-name-correctly), for instance), but that process doesn't scale.

One solution suggests using the phonetic last name field.  I don't want to have to repeat that thirty times.

Another solution goes through Siri to teach it how to pronounce the name.  This doesn't scale either - Siri asks me for each contact to choose pronunciations for both the first and last names.  I don't need to correct the first names - Siri has no trouble figuring out "John" and "Mary".

What I am looking for is a way to tell Siri one time: "Weirdlastname is pronounced Smith, everywhere it occurs, preferably even for contacts I have not added yet."  Is that possible to do?

iOS version 14.1